# Saving data to Order custom fields with API in Infusionsoft

Tags: infusionsoft

I've added a couple of custom fields to the Order in the Infusionsoft and now I'm trying to save data into those fields with API. I thought I could use Update method of data service like this:

```
apiProxy.Update(InfusionsoftHelper._InfusionsoftApiKey, "Order", orderId, obj);
```

Unfortunately it does know Order table. I can't find an appropriate table name in their [documentation](https://developer.infusionsoft.com/docs/table-schema/).

Has anyone done something similar? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "Order" table is called "[Job](https://developer.infusionsoft.com/docs/table-schema/)" in the API.

Comment: Thanks Bradley, that was not obvious, but it is mentioned in documentation.